# docker: invalid reference format on Elixir Umbrella project

Tags: docker, elixir, umbrella

following [this tutorial](https://cultivatehq.com/posts/elixir-distillery-umbrella-docker/) I'm trying to dockerize my Elixir Umbrella project before pushing to production.

I'm trying to run my app through Docker using this command:

```
docker run --rm -ti \
             -p 4000:4000 \
             -e COOKIE=a_cookie \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=UserName \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=Password \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_REALM=realm \ political_project:0.1.0
```

I get the following error: `docker: invalid reference format. See 'docker run --help'.`

As I am new to Docker, I have no clue what the problem might come from.

when I run `docker images`, I get:

```
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
political_project                 0.1.0               0618eaa9fcf0        8 minutes ago       54.7MB
<none>                            <none>              ce28b64790a6        8 minutes ago       370MB
bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix   latest              cc054692aa5e        37 hours ago        311MB
alpine                            3.6                 43773d1dba76        12 days ago         4.03MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the last blackslash right in front of the image name

```
docker run --rm -ti \
             -p 4000:4000 \
             -e COOKIE=a_cookie \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=UserName \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=Password \
             -e BASIC_AUTH_REALM=realm political_project:0.1.0
```

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Thank you very much for your help !